# use expect to spawn command with arguments containing spaces

Tags: bash, automation, automated-tests, expect

I want to use `expect` to run a simple command `cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub` over ssh.

In a shell, I can run this wo problem, (with manually put in the password)

```
ssh root@localhost 'cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub'
```

I want to automate this with `expect`. My `expect` script is,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
eval spawn ssh root@localhost 'cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub'
expect "password:"
send "123456"
expect eof
```

It throws error `bash: cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory`. it looks very strange to me. What could be the possible cause?

Edit: after some testing, I find this is common, not only in the case of `cat`. If the argument to spawned command is with space (even if it's in the quotes), it will have problem. For example, replacing `cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub` with other commands with spaces, like

```
eval spawn ssh root@localhost 'which java'
```

it complains with `bash: which java: command not found`. But if replacing that with `pwd`, like

```
eval spawn ssh root@localhost 'pwd'
```

it work fine.

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes around 'command argument'? It appears that the root of the problem is it's trying to interpret the entire quoted string as the name of a command, rather than splitting it into command and arguments...

Comment: @twalberg that's working. I also tried double quotes, wo/ problem as well. Just out of curiosity, can u explain a bit what's special about single quotes?

Comment: I'd have to dig out the `expect` docs to see what it says - don't know off the top of my head. I suggested that based on the syntax of the particular error message you were getting...

Answer (score 9):

Single quotes (`'`) have no special meaning to Expect, unlike sh and other compatible shells.
This means that your statment

```
spawn ssh root@localhost 'cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub'
```

is parsed into the following words:

- `spawn`
- `ssh`
- `root@localhost`
- `'cat` - not until the other single quote.
- `/tmp/id_rsa.pub'`

The usage in sh is to group this to a single argument. In Tcl you could either use double quotes (`"`) or curly brackets (`{}`). Inside double quotes, Tcl variables will be substituted, while the content inside `{}` is passed without any substitution<sup>1</sup>.

**tl;dr** The Expect/Tcl equivalent of sh's `'` are `{}`.

<sup><sup>1</sup> A `\` before a newline will still be substitued.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

As Johannes said, using `'` doesn't work.
I had a similar problem, but I wanted to execute more commands and then still get a login shell. I managed to make it work with `"`:

```
expect -c "
   set timeout 5;
   spawn ssh -XY $user@$host -t \"cat /etc/motd; bash -l\"
   expect {
      -re \"^Warning.*\" {exp_continue}
      -re \"^.*sword: \" {send \"${PASSWORDS[$user]}\r\"; interact}
   }
"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't require `eval` there. Remove it and check.

Check this [expect examples link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Examples) for detailed examples on "how to use `expect`?" .

Hope this helps.